# PHP GD Distort Perspective

Tags: php, gd

I am currently using the following class to distort the perspective of my image;
https://github.com/nchourrout/GD-Perspective/blob/master/perspective.class.php

Here is my code;

```
$newTex->createPerspective(
    $points[4], $points[5],             //[2]
    $points[6] , $points[7],            //[3]
    $points[0], $points[1],             //[0]
    $points[2], $points[3],             //[1]
);
```

However, it would appear the the pixels are being removed in the image after the perspective change has happened. I don't understand why.

Here you can see the image before the perspective change has occured;
[image]

However after rendering it I get the following

[image]

It is rendering in the correct position, just some of the pixels have been remove. Any ideas how I would fix this? or construct some sort of pattern match to manually fill them in.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks xD!

I would like to do this using GD rather than external extensions such as Imagick. However, you could alternatively provide an example in Imagick and I could have a look! That would also be brilliant.